# Swift How can I remove these button programmaticaly or change their action when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, abaddressbook, addressbookui

In my application I have to remove this two kind of buttons or give them another function. There were 3 days reading the net and I can't even find how they are called. So to the question: How can I programmaticaly remove them, access them, change their action when tapped? So any help will be appreciated.

[image: Buttons marked in red]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only enable/disable these buttons using `allowsActions` property but cannot change the actions associated with them.

> Determines whether to display buttons for actions such as sending a text message or initiating a FaceTime call.

```
var allowsActions: Bool
```

> By default the value of this property is true.

Refer to the Apple’s [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContactViewController/allowsEditing)

Comment: Based on Your suggestion I wrote an extension to totally disable this buttons but maybe something is wrong. This code doesn't work for hiding this buttons ... Is there something wrong in the code/idea:

extension ABPersonViewController {

    override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.allowsActions = false;
    }

}

Comment: You're not calling super.viewWillAppear

Comment: I've tried that on instance of ABPersonViewController and it's working. I'll check with the extension as well and will get back to you.

Comment: The method “viewWillAppear" that you are trying to override is defined in ABPersonViewController, and not to one of its superclasses. And you can't override a method which is defined in the same class. You have to use swizzling to implement that which is a bit complex. I would suggest doing it with the instance of ABPersonViewController.